# How to find a hash key containing a matching value for a hash having array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have situation like this:

```
clients = {
"yellow"=>[{"client_id"=>"2178","price" => 1},{"client_id" => "2282","price" => 2}], 
"orange"=>[{"client_id"=>"2180","price" => 1},{"client_id" => "2283","price" => 3}],
"red"=>[{"client_id"=>"2178","price" => 1},{"client_id" => "2282","price" => 3}],
"blue"=>[{"client_id"=>"2180","price" => 1},{"client_id" => "2283","price" => 1}]
 }
```

I need to get the key(s) with client ids => [2282,2178] and get the lowest key value based on price.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I tried with clients.select{|key, hash| hash["label"] == "Pepsi" } but it returns Type Error

Comment: did you just changed the complete question?

Comment: no @shivam why you guys are voting it down I dont know

Comment: The hash is not formatted properly, key, value pairs should be seperated by comma. Please try and post valid code always so that other users find it easier to focus on the problem at hand.

Comment: Edited the code please check @AlokSwain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = []
client.each{|k, v|
 res << k if  v.detect{|hash| hash["client_id"] == "2282"}
}
res
#=> ["red", "yellow"]
```

**NOTE**
This answer is for OPs original question that required finding keys that contained "client_id" = 2282. I have not updated my answer as OP changed the requirement quite lazily.

Comment: returns an empty array for me.. :(

Comment: Why i rejected your edit: you changed `detect` to `select`. If you read here http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html you will understand `detect` finds the first occurrence and return its value. `select` on the other hand goes on matching all the enums, making it inefficient in this case. If `select` is working there is no way for `detect` not to work (unless you are doing something completely wrong). I have tested the code in my console with data posted by you. I'm 100% confident about my answer.

Comment: also you tried to remove `NOTE` at the end of my answer failing which you rejected my answer (after already accepting it and commenting it solved your problem), which is completely unethical!

Comment: that will work too but it wont be efficient as I already explained above. If you have better solution please submit is as answer and accept it. But changing my enum in answer is essentially equivalent to changing my whole answer. Which I do not approve as I know I have written more efficient code compared to what you proposed.